# Combinatorics - Standard 52-card deck

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, binomial-coefficients

How many possible ways there are to choose 5 cards from a Standard 52-card deck, in a way that between those 5 cards there will be exactly three cards with the same number?

In a Standard 52-card deck there are 4 suits and 13 enumerable cards.

1º) Choose a number between 1 and 13. You can do that in ${13\choose 1}$ ways.

2º) Choose 3 from the 4 suits. You can do that in ${4\choose 3}$ ways

3º) Now get your three cards with the number that you've decided. You can do that in only one way.

4º) Finally, choose 2 cards from the remaining ($52-3=49$) cards. You can do that in ${49\choose 2}$ ways. Therefore, by the multiplication principle:
$$
{13\choose 1}{4\choose 3}{49\choose 2}
$$
Is it correct? I'm a complete beginner in combinatorics... Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: your choice for the remaining cards is out of *48*, not *49*, because you don't want to choose the card with the number that you chose and suit you didn't choose, since you want *exactly* three cards with the same number, hence want to avoid the possibility of all four coming. Aside from this, I don't see any issues.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг That makes sense... If the question was, with AT LEAST 3 card with the same number the answer was the one that I gave? Thank you

Comment: No, you will have to be a little careful there.

Comment: For "at least 3", it would make sense to just count the two cases "exactly 3" and "exactly 4".

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct, since you want exactly 3 cards that have the same number. The correct answer should be $\binom{13}1\binom43\binom{48}2$ since you can not choose the same number to the other 3 cards. Even if the question is AT LEAST $3$ cards, then still there are double counting. For example, 1,1,1,1,13 is counted 4 times.